I can't modify the postion of a image with tailwind-css and reactJS
hello i got a problem whatever i try to move my picture it doesnt move i'm kinda new to typescript and react
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import {Form, FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { SignupValidation } from "@/lib/validation";
import { z } from "zod";


return (
    <div>
        <Form {...form}>
          <div className="sm:w-420 flex-center flex-col">
            <img src="/assets/images/image2vector.svg" alt="logo" className="ml-100 sm:ml-0" />
          </div>

i tried to change the values but no success
this is what it gave me image.png

You have not used the margin-left property the right way.
There is no ml-100 in the official documents of tailwind.
Try this one to set the margin-left:100px; for screens above small screens (above 640px) and for small screens (upto 640px) margin left will be 0. I guess you intend to do that from your code.
  <img src="/assets/images/image2vector.svg" alt="logo" className="block ml-[100px]" />



weird it doesnt change anything all i want is just to place the svg logo a little bit to the left

On Which screen you want to keep the svg logo little bit to the left?
Also, is the tailwind configured correctly in the project

the little logo on the left i want it a little on the left i will make it bigger later and yeah tailwind is configured because when i try to modify other then the logo it make it

can we add each other to discord or something like that so it's easy please ?

Happy to help :) Did you checked the developer console and check the values?

Just try this  class : className="ml-[100px] block", see if there is any change?

ohhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!! it's working omg i love u dude omg omg why this is working and not the previous answer?

The previous answer made sure it works for both mobile and desktop. For mobile I thought you want margin-left:0px and above 640px devices you want a margin-left of 100px :) Anyways very happy to help.
God bless you

do you have any advice or tutorial for starting reactjs or typescript?

or even with taildwind thanks btw

Are you new to coding :)
There are obviously a lot of resources

Are you on Linkedin?

i'm very new to coding i have some vocabulary but i'm really new i have the project of making a social app like twitter and now i'm just following a video that show the basic of how to start and no i'm not on Linkedin i only have 17 haha

I appreciate your passion for coding. little sister! Coding is a uphill task, never impossible though. But it takes a lot of dedication and hard work.
Do you use any social media like facebook, etc so that I can share with you the resources to learn from (if you are serious about coding)

done i vote it !

i have instagram if you want

Thanks for upvote.
I use insta less but I can help you share what is required.
This is my linkedin profile https://www.linkedin.com/in/imran-rafiq-rather/ and you may create one account as it is more towards professionals and will help you in your career

Sure, you may share your Instagram  Id and I will guide you will Frontend related resources God Willing!

okay thanks i'll create an account

Once you create your account drop me a message, I will guide you with Frontend career path God Willing!

i added you i need to pay a subscription for messaging you

Is it hehhee! I don't know.

I accepted your request
